# effect of vote up and down on user profile

Tags: support, voting

If I do randomly vote ups on random questions/answers is there any adverse effect happened on my user profile?

If yes what type of adverse effects will be there?

Comment: why would you vote randomly in the first place?

Comment: to just get some badges for voting on questions and answers

Comment: You could try *not* randomly voting, but actually voting on answers and questions that deserve votes?

Comment: yes but if i do it just for doing it up vote then does it affect my profile on SO

Comment: Why would anyone feel good about getting badges for voting randomly on questions/answers, if the purpose of doing so was just to get badges? I'm so confused. Perhaps you misunderstand the purpose of the site.

Comment: Hope you are not planning on randomly flagging posts for the [Marshal Badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1298/marshal)....

Comment: yes actually I am not planing to do that just want to know the effect of it in profile

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the adjective you means to write was [adverse](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adverse).  Meaning a *negative* effect on your profile.

> what type of [adverse] effects will there be

If that is what you mean then **there is no adverse effect.**

## However

You **did** use the word `reverse` and that *also plays a role* to play when dealing with voting.
If during a random voting spree a user vote multiple times on **one specific user's answers** , and if the [voting fraud script](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) *detects that behavior*, all the `-1`'s that were deducted from downvoting will be returned to you (reversed).  The same happens if the voting script detects fraudulent upvotes.  However in that case there is no effect on the "victim's" profile - they will just get their *ill-gotten rep* taken away (reversed)...

If this happens on more than one occasion the user might be eligible for a mod message and/or a [slap on the wrist](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)...

---

That said - please don't just cast random votes in order to get badges.... You can just as easily **vote correctly** on posts and get the badge in anycase.  There is no shortage of posts to vote on.  Throwing around random votes really upsets the system becuase those votes count for the helpfulness of the post.  The more people who upvote the answer; the more that answer will be regarded as a *good answer* and vice versa for bad answers.

<sub>No random votes on this post please ;)</sub>

Comment: I think I read somewhere that serial upvoting is also detected by the script?

Comment: Thanks i just want to know is there any system which track my up/down votes as fraud and is there any reputation reduction for that

Comment: @nha - Yes - [upvoting is also caught by the voting fraud script.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/172936)

Comment: @Lix: I think you should edit your post.

Comment: @nha - added info about upvoting....